# Troubleshooting PHP Login connection

Tags: php, function

I have encountered a problem that I have not come accross yet when setting up a log in page using php.

The page has a error message that relates to line 1 ( `require_once('../Connections/Login.php)`

that states

> [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> Fatal Error: require_once() [function.require]: failed opening required ... (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear-php5')

I know it is probably really simple and stupid, but I'm really struggling to self-troubleshoot and would really value some help please?

---

This is where I have been so confused.  I also thought the same, that it just couldn't find the file; however the structure is just as you have said:

htdocs/comparison.php (the log in page)
htdocs/Connections/connComparisonLogin.php

Sorry this is going to confuse you, I simplified the actual script in my original question and here is the actual error message:

> Warning: require_once(../Connections/connComparisonLogin.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fhlinux135/s/suzukigenuine.com/user/htdocs/comparison.php on line 1
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../Connections/connComparisonLogin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear-php5') in /home/fhlinux135/s/suzukigenuine.com/user/htdocs/comparison.php on line 1

Have I done it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your require statement should be:

```
require_once 'Connections/connComparisonLogin.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "Connections/Login.php" relative to the currrent php file.

php will look for the file relative to the current file, or, in one of the directories specified in the "include_path" php.ini setting.

Answer (score 0):

The error just means php can't find the Login.php file.  Assuming the page you are calling is index.php you should have a director structure like

```
-Dir1 
|-index.php
-Connections 
|-Login.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going up a directory in your require statement? Remove the "../" from the beginning of your require_once path.